# Using Excel as the front end, Azure as the backend

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I have a SQL Database on Azure to which I can successfully get connected from within an Excel file. I am using ADO and the connection string uses my own username and password. Since this file will be used by many users, how can I create a generic login and password so that I would not give out my own username and password in the code? The Excel file runs many VBA macros to communicate with the Azure SQL database.

I am using Excel 2010 (yeah, it is old, I have to) and this is my connection string:

```
mstrConnectionString = "Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};" & _
                        "Server=tcp:<servername>.database.windows.net,1433;" & _
                        "Database=<databasename>;" & _
                        "Uid=<myusername>@<servername>;" & _
                        "Pwd={MyPassword};" & _
                        "Encrypt=yes;Connection Timeout=30;"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According your comment, I have an idea that you can create a new login/user for you Azure SQL database.

Then you use this user and password as public account to get or writer data from your Azure SQL database within Excel.

Here's the example T-SQL statement, this code is create a new login and a user in your Azure SQL database. You can run this query in SSMS:

```
--running in master db
USE [master]
GO
CREATE LOGIN [sagarreadonly] WITH PASSWORD='password'
GO
-- running in Azure SQL DB
USE [DataEncryptDemo]
GO
CREATE USER [sagarreadonly] FOR LOGIN [sagarreadonly] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = Marketing; 
GO
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_owner', 'sagarreadonly';
GO
```

The new user is created as 'db_owner' to the specified database.

For more details about database roles, please see [Database-Level Roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/database-level-roles?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15).

About login and user:

- A login is used for user authentication
- A database user account is used for database access and permissions
  validation.

Logins are associated to users by the security identifier (SID). A login is required for access to the SQL Server server. The process of verifying that a particular login is valid is called "authentication". This login must be associated to a SQL Server database user. You use the user account to control activities performed in the database. If no user account exists in a database for a specific login, the user that is using that login cannot access the database even though the user may be able to connect to SQL Server.

A Login is an identity used to connect to a SQL Server instance. A User allows you to log into a SQL Server database and is mapped to a Login. So you will need to first create a Login, before you can create a User in SQL Server.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Why readonly? The users will create records in some tables so the user should be able to write too

Comment: @Ibo Oh I see. But if you want, you can give other permission to them. Just by change the  Database_level Roles. You don't need to give they your own user and password. Just create new one for them.

Comment: I will try this next week and get back to you

Comment: @Ibo Ok, if you tried it and works, please accept(mark) it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: It worked, thanks! just to make your answer more helpful please add comments to explain what the approach is, for example, the difference between a login and a user and why one should do these steps in order. In that case, I will give your answer +1 so that you get all the credit possible from my side. BTW make the comment that for example Marketing is an example and should be changed based on readers' need

Comment: @Ibo, I add it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a "Database login" dialog box to prompt a user for database connection information by using text boxes, buttons, or other dialog box controls. Typically, when you type text in a text box, the text appears as you type. However, you can use a property of the Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications (VBA) Edition User Form to create the effect of a hidden or "masked" text box for creating a password dialog box, where you do not want the text that is typed in a text box to be "visible". [Here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/830258/how-to-create-a-masked-password-dialog-box-in-office-programs-by-using) you will find how to do that.

The information the user types on the "Database login" can be used to build the connection string you posted above.

To create a custom dialog in Excel please follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/Concepts/Controls-DialogBoxes-Forms/create-a-custom-dialog-box) instructions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i don’t want to force users to login I just want to create a login and password on the azure side